# How to control your iPad with your Mac remotely?

Tags: ipad, mac, remote-control

I would like to know, is there a way to control your iPad with your Mac remotely (be able to see and manipulate iPad's desktop on your Mac)? I know that with the TeamViewer or other programs you can control your Mac with your iPad but not vice versa.

Comment: Technically a dupe of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52730/any-way-to-remotely-control-or-at-least-view-an-ipad-without-jailbreaking but this question has far more views.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is not possible to remotely control the screen of an iPad unless you jailbreak and install a VNC server as MattDMo suggested. This is because the security model in iOS does not allow an app to reach outside of its sandbox to control other apps or the springboard home screen. Apple does not provide any remote control functionality at the iOS level either. There is no way to do what you are asking for without jailbreaking.

Mobile Device Management (MDM) solutions do not allow remote control of the screen on iOS either. MDM can push configuration profiles to control settings on an iPad, or prompt the user to install an app from the app store, but they can't control the screen. Airwatch offers a screen control option, but this only works on platforms that support it (not iOS). I work with several MDM vendors, including Airwatch, and this is not possible because Apple does not make this functionality available in iOS.

Comment: Great summary; to potentially save others a trip to acronymfinder.com: MDM = Mobile Device Management.

Comment: ***"..and this is not possible because Apple does not make this functionality.."***

Comment: And Apple has less APIs than products

Comment: If it's not possible then how does SeeTest do it:  https://youtu.be/K3eAxRGYYlU ?

Comment: @AleksandrLevchuk It wasn't possible at the time of writing. Some of the newer answers might explain...

Answer (score 4):

There's a tool (made for testing purposes) with the ability to do that, first released on July 18, 2014: [iOS Gateway](http://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/ePF/using/epf-getting-started-ios-gateway.htm)

[image: iOS Gateway Network Architecture]

Enjoy!

Comment: How does this work and is the accepted answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104799/237 wrong?

Comment: I don't know how they do behind the scenes but It works So It should be wrong accepted answer. Just plug your device and open this tool. Nothin' fancy

Comment: Have you used it a quick view of their docs on that screen seem to imply it runs scripts on the IOS device not remotely controls it

Comment: The tool is kind of VNC. They have an IDE to write scripts that tell the IOSGateway tap to specific location. I have been using it for 3 years to remote ipad plugin to my mac at home from my office.

Comment: So does it all you to "be able to see and manipulate iPad's desktop on your Mac" as the question asks?

Comment: Yes, it absolutely can do that.

Comment: @user151019 Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options. [iKeyboardRemote](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ikeyboardremote/id446670061?mt=12) is an app that claims to do just what you want, and is free. However, after installing it, it seems like it's limited to pressing the home button, looking at Pictures, and playing music.

A second option is to jailbreak the iPad and install the VNC server [Veency](http://cydia.saurik.com/info/veency/) through Cydia. You can then use a VNC viewer like the [one from RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) to connect.

Comment: It looks like there's an enhanced version of iKeyboard that gives you (more) keyboard access on iOS, but you have to pay for it: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ikeyboard/id441439411?mt=12

Answer (score 1):

You can remotely control your iOS device's screen using one of many Mobile Device Management solutions, such as [AirWatch](http://www.air-watch.com/solutions/mobile-device-management) for example. However, these are enterprise-level tools that are typically used in the workplace. There is no easy way to do this as a home user, unless you enroll in such a program.

You can also jailbreak your iPad and [install a VNC server](http://lifehacker.com/5780908/how-to-install-a-vnc-server-on-your-jailbroken-ios-device).

Comment: Thank you, but I would be more interested in legal solutions for home users.

Comment: Jailbreaking is legal under the DMCA in the United States. However, if you do not want to jailbreak, then the answer is "no".

Comment: Since your location is listed as UK, I thought I would also add that it is considered legal under the Copyright and Related Rights Regulations 2003 law.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one (extremely limited) way that I can think of:

1. You can mirror the iPhone screen using [QuickTime](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/two-different-ways-to-mirror-an-ios-device-to-a-mac--cms-23533), which will allow you to see the screen.
2. Then, for a $9.99 fee, you can control the keyboard of your device using [1Keyboard](http://www.eyalw.com/1keyboard).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please don't give link-only answers.  We're looking for answers that provide explanations as to why it answers the question as well as why it's the best answer.  Links can change over time and then we'll lose the question-answer context.  See [answer] for info on what makes up a good answer.  - From Review -

Answer (score -2):

You can try [Reflector](https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) to mirror iOS devices on Mac.

According to [this tutorial](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/two-different-ways-to-mirror-an-ios-device-to-a-mac--cms-23533), you can use their 7-day free trial to wirelessly mirror (but not control) it, assuming the devices are on the same WiFi network.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: Unfortunately, OP would also like to be able to **control** the device.