# Can I view iPad screen from Mac?

Tags: ipad, video

There are several questions that ask whether you can control an iPad from a Mac (like [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84722/how-to-control-your-ipad-with-your-mac-remotely)). But is it possible to view your iPad screen from a Mac when it's plugged in via USB or wirelessly without jailbreaking it?

I can remote login to my Mac at work and my iPad is connected so I can debug on it via XCode, but I can't see the results.

Answer (score 4):

You can with Yosemite & iOS 8

Launch Quicktime player & select File > New Movie Recording [Cmd/opt/N]
Click on the small downward-facing triangle next to the record button. This lets you select an alternate recording source, which now includes your iPhone or iPad.

Comment: NB: This works when the device is connected via USB, but not over wifi.

Comment: My iPad 3 is connected via USB but I'm not seeing it as an option. Is there anything else I need to set, e.g. permission in iOS?

Comment: it may depend on what you are remote logging with, some screen-sharing won't share overlay video at all, some can't interact with attached USB devices. I'm not sure of one that will do both, tbh, might have to test a few

Comment: That's without remote logging, just on the Mac with iPad connected via USB.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this myself but this seems like what you might be looking for. It mirrors iPad to the Mac or PC wirelessly. No jail breaking required. http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/

Comment: I have used Reflector and it works really well over Wifi. Both the computer and the iDevice have to be on the same Wifi network.