# Can I remotely control an IPad 9.7 running ios 11.2 with Teamviewer on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: ipad

My mother has just bought herself a new IPAD 9,7 running IOS 11.2. I would like to set up Teamviewer so that I can control her IPad from my MacBook. So far I can only "view" her IPad when I start a screen recording, but have no control over the ipad itself. Is this functionality available with Teamviewer?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84722/how-to-control-your-ipad-with-your-mac-remotely/228901

Answer (score 2):

[No.](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mobile-apps/)

> Access remote computers on the go with the TeamViewer: Remote Control apps for Android, iOS, Windows 10 Mobile, Windows 10, and BlackBerry. Use your mobile device to provide spontaneous support or to remotely access an unattended computer

There's simply no APIs available to do this AFAIK. Even Apple's own [Apple Remote Desktop](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-remote-desktop/id409907375?mt=12) can't control iOS devices.

Comment: There are [a few exceptions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228901/210513).

Comment: @Userthatisnotauser Somewhat confused as to how that program controls the iOS device over USB. Is it simply capturing the screen while emulating a mouse and keyboard?